# Sql query to find the all subordinates under a single superior

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, recursion, common-table-expression

My Table contains Three columns and the value looks like the following

```
Emp_ID |  Emp_Name   |  Emp_Manager_ID
========================================
1      |  Admin      |   Null         
2      |  John       |   1            
3      |  Sam        |   2             
4      |  Mike       |   2            
5      |  Jeff       |   4            
6      |  Ben        |   3            
7      |  Vicky      |   5
```

The parameter id @Emp_ID = 2 
The expected result to find all the subordinates under the given Emp_Id
so the result should be all EmpIDs `3,4,5,6,7`
because 2  is the manager of 3,4 and 3 is the manager of 6, 4 is the manager of 5 and 5 is the manager of 7

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of the CTE working.  Let me know if you run into other issues with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a [Recursing CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx). This currently returns all three columns.  Remove `Emp_Name` and `Emp_Manager_ID` from the `SELECT` if you do not require that information.

```
WITH Subordinates AS
(
   SELECT e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_Name, e.Emp_Manager_ID
   FROM Employee AS e
   WHERE e.Emp_Manager_ID = 2
   
   UNION ALL

   SELECT e.Emp_ID, e.Emp_Name, e.Emp_Manager_ID
   FROM Employee AS e
   INNER JOIN Subordinates AS sub ON e.Emp_Manager_ID = sub.Emp_ID
)
SELECT s.Emp_ID, s.Emp_Name, s.Emp_Manager_ID
FROM Subordinates AS s
```

[Example of query running using Employee_ID = 1:](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120005/)

Comment: The issue was solved in my table the first rown manager id was 1 it goes through an infinite loop then